# no logro sumar los números impares de la función fibonnacci

Tags: javascript

Dado un entero positivo num, devuelve la suma de todos los números impares de Fibonacci que son menores o iguales a num. Los dos primeros números en la secuencia de Fibonacci son 1 y 1. Cada número adicional en la secuencia es la suma de los dos números anteriores. Los seis primeros números de la secuencia de Fibonacci son 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 y 8. Por ejemplo, sumFibs(10) debe devolver 10 porque todos los números impares de Fibonacci menores o iguales a 10 son 1, 1, 3 y 5.

Hint 1
sumFibs(1000) debe devolver 1785.

Hint 2
sumFibs(4000000) debe devolver 4613732.

Hint 3
sumFibs(4) debe devolver 5.

```
function sumFibs(n) {


    let i;
    let fib = []; // Initialize array!
    let suma;

    fib[0] = 1;
    fib[1] = 1;
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
        // Translated to JavaScript:
        fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
        } // en este punto se guarda la secuencia

    for (let j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
        if (fib[j] % 2 !== 0 && fib[j] < n){
            suma = suma + fib
        }
    }
    return suma

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Son válidos los aportes de los compañeros, pero creo que se puede reducir el código un poco más.

Revisando la lógica de la sucesion de Fibonacci y lo que requieres, comparto mi aporte:

```js
function sumFibs(limit) {
  let sumatoria = 2;
  let before1 = 1;
  let before2 = 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < limit; i++) {

    const sucesion = before1 + before2;
    before1 = before2;
    before2 = sucesion;

    if (sucesion <= limit && sucesion % 2 !== 0) {
      sumatoria += sucesion;
    }

    // Si deseas cortar el ciclo cuando ya se deba se puede anexar el siguiente if
    if (sucesion > limit) {
        break;
    }
  }

  return sumatoria;
}

console.log(4, sumFibs(4));
console.log(10, sumFibs(10));
console.log(1000, sumFibs(1000));
console.log(4000, sumFibs(4000));
console.log(4000000, sumFibs(4000000));
```

Espero te sirva, Saludos.

Comment: Si, algo así pensé cuando leí el problema, una solución con un solo ciclo `for`, muy pro.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de igual manera todas las respuestas me parecieron muy acertadas y válidas.

Comment: No, la mia es super densa, pesada y lenta, me guié por el codigo de la pregunta. Pero igual, tu respuesta y la de Facundo no se me ocurriría tan rápido.

Comment: Pensaba hacer lo mismo, pero dije, mejor lo hago desde cero y ps ese es el resultado. Claro que el código va sujeto a las necesidades, porque se puede ampliar si decidimos hacer una serie de validaciones extra. Como lo son que pasa si se manda un valor negativo en el parámetro, o el valor es 0, etc.

Comment: Pero, bueno ya son otras cosas que se deben tener en cuenta.

Comment: Si, la verdad no las puse porque pueden ser cosas que se validen antes de ingresar a la función o se deciden validar directamente en la función. Si lo piden pues se anexa y se da un valor por defailt en caso tal de que el parámetro no cumpla con el valor requerido.

Answer (score 2):

fijate si con este algoritmo logras lo que buscas.

La primer linea, el For, solo se encarga de completar la secuencia de fibonacci directamente en el array.

la segunda linea, el Reduce, solo suma los impares menores que el maximo.

La tercer linea, devuelve ambos valores para su uso.

*Edit: Se mejoro la cantidad de iteraciones, para limitarlas al numero indicado.

```js
function sumaFib(max,fib=[1,1]){
  console.time(max)
  for(let x=2;x<=max;x++){
      var actual = fib[x-2]+fib[x-1]
      actual>max ? x=max : fib.push(actual)
  }
  let suma=fib.reduce((p,item) => ((item%2!==0 && item<=max)*item)+p,0)
  
  console.timeEnd(max)
  
  return { secuencia:fib,   suma:suma   }
}

let respuesta= sumaFib(10)
console.log("Secuencia",respuesta.secuencia)
console.log("suma",respuesta.suma)


respuesta= sumaFib(4000)
console.log("Secuencia",respuesta.secuencia)
console.log("suma",respuesta.suma)


respuesta= sumaFib(4000000)
console.log("Secuencia",respuesta.secuencia)
console.log("suma",respuesta.suma)
```

Aca agregue otra forma, mas simplificada.

```js
function sumaFib2(max,f=[1,1]){
  for( x=2, n=f[x-2]+f[x-1] ; x<=max && n<max ;  x++ , n=f[x-2]+f[x-1] ){f.push(n)}

  return {
        secuencia:f,
        suma:f.reduce((p,i) => ((i%2!==0 && i<=max)*i)+p,0)
        }

}

console.log(sumaFib2(10).secuencia)
console.log(sumaFib2(10).suma)
```

Mirando la respuesta del compañero, se me "ocurrió" como compactar el reduce.

```js
function sumaFib(max,f=[1,1],suma=2){
    
  for( x=2, n=f[x-2]+f[x-1]; x<=max && n<max ;  x++, n=f[x-2]+f[x-1] ){
      f.push(n) 
      suma+=n%2!=0?n:0
  }
  
  return { secuencia:f, suma:suma }
}

[4,10,1000,4000,4000000].forEach(
        n => { 
    console.time(n) 
            let res = sumaFib(n)
            console.log(n,"Secuencia",res.secuencia)
            console.log(n,"Suma",res.suma)
    console.timeEnd(n)
})
```

Comment: Pero si es como raro hacer ese `for` tan largo, convendría como un `while`, tocaría analizarlo mejor

Comment: El for es solo la linea, ahi lo separe para mas claridad.

Comment: Si, me refiero no a la linea. Me refiero es a la cantidad de ciclos, en tu ejemplo por lo menos, para qué hacer 10 ciclos?... Igual en mi respuesta yo también lo hago así, pero podría optimizarse.

Comment: Es la misma cantidad de ciclos que realizas en tu for, para completar los 10 primero numeros de fibonacci, ¿vos te refieres a que podria cortar antes y solo completar los que sean menores a N?

Comment: Si yo también lo hago asi :(, y eso con 10, son 5 ciclos que sobran... imagina el ejemplo con los 4 millones... son casi 4 millones de ciclos que no sirven para nada.

Comment: Ahi le agregue tu acertada sugerencia.

Comment: Si, sabía que se podía hacer. Pero lo hiciste de manera rápida.

Answer (score 1):

Te falta comenzar la variable suma en 0 `suma = 0` y en el segundo ciclo estas haciendo esto `suma = suma + fib` debes cambiar por `suma = suma + fib[j]`

```js
    function sumFibs(n) {
    
    
      let i;
      let fib = []; // Initialize array!
      let suma = 0;
    
      fib[0] = 1;
      fib[1] = 1;
      for (i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
          // Next fibonacci number = previous + one before previous
          // Translated to JavaScript:
          fib[i] = fib[i - 2] + fib[i - 1];
          } // en este punto se guarda la secuencia
    
      for (let j = 0; j < fib.length; j++) {
          if (fib[j] % 2 !== 0 && fib[j] < n){
              suma = suma + fib[j]
          }
      }
      return suma
    
    }
    
    console.log({ sumFibs4: sumFibs(4) })
    console.log({ sumFibs10: sumFibs(10) })
    console.log({ sumFibs1000: sumFibs(1000) })
    console.log({ sumFibs4000000: sumFibs(4000000) })
```

Aunque en el primer ciclo debes revisar porque estas haciendo un ciclo muy largo y no es necesario, pero eso te lo dejo para que revises.